# ttl not working in loopback when I set it for a Model

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to set `ttl` for a loopback model so that the document gets deleted automatically after specified time. 
Here is the property I have added:

```
"ttl": {
    "type": "number",
    "required": true
}
```

This is not `AccessToken` model but a separate model whose documents I want to be deleted after specified time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to this solve as follows:

```
MyCollection.getDataSource().connector.connect(function(err, db) {
    if(!err){
        var collection = db.collection('MyCollection');
        collection.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } );
    }

});
```

Then for each document, I inserted `expireAt`which corresponds to the time the document should expire.
MongoDB automatically deletes documents from the collection at the documents’ `expireAt` time.

Answer (score 2):

`AccessTokens` don't get deleted after their `ttl` is up, they just invalidate the token for login purposes.  <s>I'm not sure that any database/ORM will just delete rows after they've been around for a certain mount of time</s>  I was wrong [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) does this, **however loopback does not actually use this feature**.  This script will create a job which deletes all rows who have expired according to their `ttl` column.

`server/boot/job-delete-expired.js`

```
module.exports = (server) => {
    const myModel = server.models.myModel;

    if (!myModel) {
        throw new Error("My model not found!");
    }

    const deleteExpiredModels = async () => {
        const now = new Date();
        const all = await myModel.find();
        // If the created time + the ttl is paste now then it can be deleted
        const expired = all.filter(m => (m.created + m.ttl) > now);
        // Delete them all
        await Promise.all(expired.map(e => myModel.destroyById(e.id)));
    };

    // Execute this every 10 minutes
    setInterval(() => deleteExpiredModels(), 60000)
};
```

Disclaimer: This code has no error handling, and setInterval does not wait for promises to resolve, if you're using this in production consider a while loop with async/await to make sure that only one instance of `deleteExpiredModels` is ever executed.

Comment: Thanks, but `mongodb` does has this feature of auto deleting documents after specifed time intervals. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/
It uses `db.collection.createIndex`, but I am not sure how I can do this through loopback

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that.  Edited my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I used the model.json file to solve this

```
"indexes":{
    "expireAt_1":{
        "keys": {"createdOn": 1},
        "options":{"expireAfterSeconds": 2592000}
     }
}
```

I used a name for the index.
The key defined has the object property that has the date value.
The expireAfterSeconds value needs to be set in the options property.In this case I have set it to 30 days after createdOn date